Vuetify v-slider doesnt show thumb and track line while printing page
When printing a page in the browser, the thumb and track of the Vuetify v-slider disappear. I tried changing the background of the slider container with CSS, but that didn't work either. I suspect the slider's state changes due to resizing when the browser prepares the page for printing.


you can test it in vuetify's official playground:
https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlkt1ugzAMhV/FylUrQWhhf4oo0p6j9CKFrGMNJEoCmoTy7gsEVlh3MWl39ucTH8vOsUevUuKuZYig1LBacmpYljcAaVl1Y+DCLtS8KpnyKUAX1qJk/JAjz/c5mkuF4EK5glC0ubAb5/Q8PhjrM87SaG7trP5oFt83NYoW13DVGmABneSiGGv+5Zv84vve1uc73xt0Etkqyb/3sDZ2ppHfchotdu9SXahKmlHCPqVQBkr2RltuoPeNSmoogc0WDhlsJgYwXYPALlijmMDjT5YQ2O9maLdjYIdRJnMUIF41V40/tGjc9+jd8bTOETmerKtV9TBXWFO5EHg4iHprkQ1Qgh9w/OzkCX7CLygwqmWnLymiwks=
i did change the style of .v-slider-container, v-slider-track and v-slider-thumb but they reset when printing the page.

The print preview from the playground does show the color of the slider.


I don't know why this happened, i tested it in firefox, edge and chrome and still doesn't show the colors. but apply this style to v-slider solved the issue:
print-color-adjust: exact;
